# List all nested properties with their full path in the containing object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects, nested-loops

I have some arrays of names stored in nested JSON like this:

```
{
    "groupZ": {
        "names": [
            "Steve",
            "Henry"
        ]
    },
    "groupY": {
        "groupA": {
            "names": [
                "Laura"
            ]
        },
        "groupB": {
            "names": [
                "Alice",
                "Bob",
                "Neil"
            ]
        }
    },
    "groupX": {
        "groupC": {
            "groupD": {
                "names": [
                    "Steph"
                ]
            }
        },
        "groupE": {
            "names": [
                "Aaron",
                "Dave"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a list of all names, prepended with the full group path for each name, so it ends up like this:

- groupZ - Steve
- groupZ - Henry
- groupY - groupA - Laura
- groupY - groupB - Alice
- groupY - groupB - Bob
- groupY - groupB - Neil
- groupX - groupC - groupD - Steph
- groupX - groupE - Aaron
- groupX - groupE - Dave

The group names will be unique at each level, but other than that could be called anything. I know I will need to recursively call a function which stops when it finds a "names" array, passing through a string to add to the prepend with each recursion, but having real trouble. Here's my code so far:

```
var sPrepend = '';
function buildList(Groups, lastGroupName){

    for(var thisGroupName in Groups) {
        var thisGroup = Groups[thisGroupName];

        if(!thisGroup.names){
            sPrepend += (' - ' + thisGroupName);
            buildList(thisGroup, thisGroupName);
        }
        if(thisGroup.names){
            thisGroup.names.forEach(function(name){
                console.log(sPrepend, ' - ', name);
                //build the list item here.
            });
        }
    }
}
buildList(oGroups, '');
```

It's got me stumped as I'm not able to change the JSON structure but I'm sure it is possible. Thanks anyone who can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function buildList(group, accum, key) {

    // default helper parameters
    accum = accum || [];
    key = key || '';

    if (group.names) {  // add each name
        group.names.forEach(function(name) {
            accum.push(key + name);
        });
    } else {            // or recurse on each key
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(group).forEach(function(gname) {
            buildList(group[gname], accum, key + gname + ' - ');
        });
    }

    return accum;
}

var list = buildList(oGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are close. You just need to ensure you are passing the concatenated group name (previous + current) to the recursive function.

Alnitak's solution is neater overall tho.

```js
function buildList(Groups, lastGroupName){

    for(var thisGroupName in Groups) {
        var thisGroup = Groups[thisGroupName];
        
        var currGroupName = lastGroupName + ' - ' + thisGroupName;

        if(!thisGroup.names){
            buildList(thisGroup, currGroupName);
        }
        if(thisGroup.names){
            thisGroup.names.forEach(function(name){
                console.log(currGroupName + ' - ' + name);
                //build the list item here.
            });
        }
    }
}

var oGroups = {
    "groupZ": {
        "names": [
            "Steve",
            "Henry"
        ]
    },
    "groupY": {
        "groupA": {
            "names": [
                "Laura"
            ]
        },
        "groupB": {
            "names": [
                "Alice",
                "Bob",
                "Neil"
            ]
        }
    },
    "groupX": {
        "groupC": {
            "groupD": {
                "names": [
                    "Steph"
                ]
            }
        },
        "groupE": {
            "names": [
                "Aaron",
                "Dave"
            ]
        }
    }
};

buildList(oGroups, '');
```

I assume you also want to return this ultimately as a list, which requires a little more effort.

```js
function buildList(Groups, lastGroupName){

    var ret = [];

    for(var thisGroupName in Groups) {
        var thisGroup = Groups[thisGroupName];
        
        var currGroupName = lastGroupName + ' - ' + thisGroupName;

        if(!thisGroup.names){
            var childNames = buildList(thisGroup, currGroupName);
            for(var i = 0; i < childNames.length; i++) {
                ret.push(childNames[i]);
            }
        }
        if(thisGroup.names){
            thisGroup.names.forEach(function(name){
                //console.log(currGroupName + ' - ' + name);
                //build the list item here.
                ret.push(currGroupName + ' - ' + name);
            });
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

var oGroups = {
    "groupZ": {
        "names": [
            "Steve",
            "Henry"
        ]
    },
    "groupY": {
        "groupA": {
            "names": [
                "Laura"
            ]
        },
        "groupB": {
            "names": [
                "Alice",
                "Bob",
                "Neil"
            ]
        }
    },
    "groupX": {
        "groupC": {
            "groupD": {
                "names": [
                    "Steph"
                ]
            }
        },
        "groupE": {
            "names": [
                "Aaron",
                "Dave"
            ]
        }
    }
};

var x = buildList(oGroups, '');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for the path and call the function without that parameter, because it will be checked and if not [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), an array is assigned.

In the loop of the keys of the object, it is checked if the key is `names` and this array is displayed with the path.

If the key is not equal to `names`, then the actual property is checked and if it is an iterable object, then the function is called again with an extended array with the actual key.

```js
function buildList(object, path) {
    path = path || [];
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k === 'names') {
            object.names.forEach(function (name) {
                console.log(path.concat(name).join(' - '));
            });
            return;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            buildList(object[k], path.concat(k));
        }
    });
}

var data = { groupZ: { names: ["Steve", "Henry"] }, groupY: { groupA: { names: ["Laura"] }, groupB: { names: ["Alice", "Bob", "Neil"] } }, groupX: { groupC: { groupD: { names: ["Steph"] } }, groupE: { names: ["Aaron", "Dave"] } } };

buildList(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```